# DOIT esp32 devkit v1 schematic confusion

Tags: capacitor, esp32

I'm creating my own small dev board for the esp32 wroom module.

I'm following the schematics for the DOIT devkit v1 module.

[image: Power Schematic]

Full schematic here: https://embedded-systems-design.github.io/overview-of-the-esp32-devkit-doit-v1/SchematicsforESP32.pdf

I'm unable to workout if I need a polarised capacitor or if I can use ceramic for all.

Given the schematics there is no plus (+) sign on the capacitors.

But on the dev board itself, I can't seem to find what the below highlighted capacitor is for.

[image: Dev board pic top]

Looking on ebay at 3.3v regulator modules, they all seem to come with ceramic only caps, so I can't say for sure if this is part of the power supply.

I'm guessing it is the 100nF C2 cap, but that is a guess and then if it is, do I need to use a Tantalum Capacitor or could go ceramic for all?

Comment: seeing the quality of the schematic you cite, I'd recommend you just directly go with the schematics from Espressif.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should generally work. In fact, usually for power supply purposes, ceramic capacitors are slightly preferable to tantalum (your polarized cap looks like a tantalum type) capacitors, because they have lower internal series resistance.

Two caveats:

- Ceramic capacitors, especially of the larger-capacitance types, have lower capacity at higher bias voltages. So, make sure your 10 µF capacitor is rated significantly higher than 3.3 V; going for anything less than 16 V rating probably is a bad idea
- In some circumstances, the higher resistance is a *feature* (not a *problem*), because it can dampen control loops and limit oscillations. That's probably not the case here.

Comment: “So, make sure your 10 µF capacitor is rated significantly higher than 3.3 V”: Increasing the voltage rating will not ireduce or compensate for the voltage dependence of the capacitance. This dependence is due to the type of and volume of the ceramic dielectric.

Comment: @RussellH absolutely right, but a 10 µF X5R rated for 50V will have roughly 10 µF at 3.3 V, whereas one rated for 6.3 V might not.

Comment: I'd really be surprised if I bought a 50 V rated ceramic capacitor and it doesn't achieve rated capacitance at a 3.3 V offset, but let me check some trustworthy vendor's datasheets

Comment: @RussellH in fact, I think that'd be a breach of contract. Thing is spec'ed to be within +- 20% over the operational range. That -20% will be reached at maximum allowable bias. Since capacitance reduction is roughly a quadratically falling thing with bias, you should be off *much* better at 10% rated voltage than at 90%.

Comment: @RussellH huh! The derating advantage for X5R from the same vendor, same package size (!), same nominal capacitance, same 3.3 V offset is by far not as pronounced as I would have thought: https://imgur.com/a/xBwpoPR

Comment: https://ksim3.kemet.com/capacitor-simulation

Comment: Here is a nice study. It appears here that voltage rating has 
 little effect. https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/temperature-and-voltage-variation-ceramic-capacitor.html. Voltage rating may increase size. In this case may reduce voltage dependance. But before committing to a particylar capacitor, bench testing would be appropriate.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bzxah.png

Comment: Nice, the takeaway then is a) check the vendor bias derating curves (the adage "always read the datasheet" doesn't help here, vendor datasheets just say "please check bias derating") and b) by tendency, figure out what the smallest SMD capacitor package with the needed capacitance, voltage ratings are, and then use two sizes larger, if you're too lazy to check the derating curves.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, quick related question. What is the point of using two of the same type of cap at two different values? Why would I not use a 1.1uF cap for example?

Comment: EDIT: I meant 10.1uF

Comment: @JamesWilliams lower-value caps can be build with better ESR and parasitic inductance; that improves the high-frequency properties. In essence, the higher the frequency of the signals a capacitor has to deal with, the more relevant inductive properties of its construction become, up to the point where capacitors have a self-resonant frequency, where they behave like a tuned LC resonator (and above that, they behave more like inductors than capacitors). Smaller (as in: smaller dimensions) caps are easier to construct with low inductance. Compared to most electrolytic caps, ceramic caps…

Comment: … tend to have significantly lower ESR, which you desire to be able to smoothen out quick load changes. Again, this is all *tendencies*, and you'd need to check the actual properties of the specific caps used. But "big bulk capacitor with high ESR and high inductance in parallel with small-capacitance small-form capacitor" is a pretty common pattern.